# Does Box2D a 2D Physics Engine have the ability to capture screen footage?

Tags: video, video-streaming, box2d, video-capture, video-processing

I could really use someone to give me a comprehensive response to my question.

I'm using a 2D Physics Engine (Box2D) and was wondering if it had video capturing capabilities? To record Game Footage and be able to share with other players.

If it doesn't I'd like to know what I could use to record gameplay footage within a canvas. If what I just said confused you. Then allow me to clarify.

If Box2D, which is a game engine, doesn't have an inbuilt capability to record video, what could I use/do to implement video recording capability within the game to record gameplay footage?

If you know how then please tell me... every option will be welcomed.

Thanks for reading guys... I hope it makes sense.

Comment: This isn't really an SO question.   Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Box2D is a physics engine as you recognized; but it's not a game engine like you also stated.

Moreover the Box2D library itself is meant to be independent of graphics. From the [Box2D FAQ](https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D/wiki/FAQ):

> ### What are Box2D's rendering capabilities?
>
> Box2D is only a physics engine. How you draw stuff is up to you.

As for recording results, you could record the numerical results from Box2D through a few mechanisms like [serializing Box2D data out to JSON](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2djson/).

If video is what you really want to record though, there are a variety of ways to do that but those have nothing to do with Box2D other than maybe being linked together with it in your application, or running on the same host OS. You'll have to write your application to use Box2D for the numerical data, render the visual elements representing those physical bodies using a graphics interface of your choice, and then tie that with a video encoding technology perhaps like [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org).

Hope this helps.